# Jenkins Cloud Foundry plugin does not seem to use the manifest.yml correctly

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to use the staticfile-buildpack for a simple HTML/CSS page on Cloud Foundry (Bluemix). When doing a manual CF push with the following manifest, I have no trouble:

```
   ---
     applications:
     - name: rrn-hasher
       memory: 64M
       host: rrn-hasher
       buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git
       stack: cflinuxfs2
```

When I try to use the [CF plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cloud+Foundry+Plugin) and set it up to choose the manifest.yml instead of manually configuring all the properties in Jenkins I get the following exception

```
 It looks like you're deploying on a stack (currently set to *lucid64*) that's not supported by this buildpack.
```

The plugin does not seem to use the **stack** entry in the **manifest.yml** for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially the [`manifest.yml` docs](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#optional-attributes) do not list `stack` as a valid configuration parameter.  I have went ahead and submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cloudfoundry/pull/8) to get it added to the Jenkins Plugin though.

Answer (score 0):

After having a quick look in the [source code](https://github.com/drissamri/cloudfoundry-jenkins/blob/master/src/main/java/com/activestate/cloudfoundryjenkins/CloudFoundryPushPublisher.java) of the plugin, it seems like it doesn't take the stack property into account.. I'll have to submit a issue or make a pull request to support it.

Comment: I made a ticket in the upstream ActiveState repository for handling the stack property. https://github.com/ActiveState/cloudfoundry-jenkins/issues/6

Comment: This has been merged into the cloud foundry jenkins plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The `stack` option is a fairly new option and it looks like the CF plugin doesn't yet support this as I can't see it parsed [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cloudfoundry/blob/5961b1e7773168b5f22986c5d0c9801b0ade9a23/src/main/java/com/activestate/cloudfoundryjenkins/CloudFoundryPushPublisher.java#L498).

You could either submit a pull request to that GitHub [project](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cloudfoundry) with the changes to support it or submit an [issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29816?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened)%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%27cloudfoundry-plugin%27).

Comment: Yeah I noticed, I wonder if I need to submit it to the Jenkins repository or the upstream one?